# How to run a code when network connection changes on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos

I need to run a script on my Mac when network connection changes, i.e. when network cable/wifi gets connected or disconnected. I do not want to use a cronjob and I'd prefer a soulution that avoids modifying system files. Is there some "network changed" hook in the mac os x I could connect on?

thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 1):

Try [MarcoPolo](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/),  though if you're running Snow Leopard, you'll probably need to 
look at the bottom of that page for the link to a patched version.

Answer (score 0):

While not directly what you ask for, maybe [columbus](http://thomas.apestaart.org/projects/columbus/) can be made part of the solution? It uses ARP traffic to help cope with a machine that for instance travels within school/home/work etc and should have correspondingly different /etc/resolv.conf or firewall settings etc.

From the README file:

> columbus : an automatic network
>   detector and configurator
>
> columbus is useful when you use your
>   machine in different networks.  It is
>   great for laptop users.
>
> columbus uses ARP pings to look for
>   known MAC-IP address correspondences.
>   It can do this even when no IP address
>   has been assigned yet, which is a good
>   idea when you are on a new network.
>
> columbus can be hooked up to your
>   network script.  It can also be hooked
>   up to your apmd and be told to
>   re-check the network each time the
>   computer wakes up.
>
> columbus also has a modified version
>   of one of Donald Becker's link check
>   tools.  This way it will check your
>   network when your network cable is
>   plugged back in and if necessary,
>   execute all synchronisation steps.